# unique objects by value and extra filter within an array of objects

Tags: arrays, filter, javascript-objects, reduce, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to get unique objects within an array of objects. Let's say the object is like below.

```js
    values = [
      { id: 10, available: true },
      { id: 10, available: false },
      { id: 11, available: true },
      { id: 12, available: false }
    ];
```

unique objects should return like below: if duplicates objects contains `available:true` need `available:true`

```js
    result = [
      { id: 10, available: true },
      { id: 11, available: true },
      { id: 12, available: false }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to your problem..
The function `myfilter()` returns a array with unique `id` values, and if any exist with `available: true` it takes precedence

```js
var values = [
      { id: 10, available: true },
      { id: 10, available: false },
      { id: 11, available: true },
      { id: 12, available: false }
    ];
    
function myfilter()
{
    var filtarray=[];
    values.forEach(function(element) {

        var idxfound = filtarray.findIndex(function(ele2) {
            return ele2.id === element.id;
        });
        
        if (idxfound==-1)
        {
          filtarray.push(element);
        }
        else {
            if (filtarray[idxfound].available==false && element.available==true)
            filtarray[idxfound].available=true;
        }

    });
    
    console.log(filtarray);
    return filtarray;
}
```